# SendInput to Remote Desktop

Tags: c++, remote-desktop, sendinput

I'm trying to debug a function which sends keys to a program within a Remote Desktop application. The function has no problem sending keys except when it tries to send the period (".") key. Here is a sample of the working code:

```
void PlayKeyboardEvent(int vkey, int bscan)
{
    INPUT input[4];
    int num_input = 0;

    // key down
    input[num_input].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[num_input].ki.wVk = vkey;
    input[num_input].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey( VkKeyScan(vkey) & 0xFF, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
    input[num_input].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    input[num_input].ki.time = 0;
    input[num_input].ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    num_input++;

    SendInput(num_input, input, sizeof(INPUT));

    // reset for the key up
    num_input = 0;

    // key up
    input[num_input].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[num_input].ki.wVk = vkey;
    input[num_input].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey( VkKeyScan(vkey) & 0xFF, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);;
    input[num_input].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    input[num_input].ki.time = 0;
    input[num_input].ki.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    num_input++;

    SendInput(num_input, input, sizeof(INPUT));

}
```

Comment: Did you try MapVirtualKeyEx() instead?